# Pip install with weird behavior (not failing but also not working)

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I have pip 8.1.1 been trying to upgrade with `pip install --upgrade pip`. The command doesn't fail but it also doesn't do anything. The output is

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 615kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Also, probably related, I'm trying to install `matplotlib` with `pip install matplotlib==2.0.0` and I'm getting the following result:

```
Collecting matplotlib==2.0.0
  Downloading matplotlib-2.0.0-1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.6MB 94kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): functools32 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.10 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): subprocess32 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.0.0)
Installing collected packages: cycler, matplotlib
  Found existing installation: cycler 0.9.0
    Not uninstalling cycler at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed cycler-0.9.0 matplotlib-2.0.0
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I can't import `matplotlib` because the `cycler` version is not up to date.

So I guess the key is the `Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr` message, but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get the reason for this, but apparently this stems from the fact that pip was installed via `apt` and I'm trying to upgrade it with pip. So the solution was to remove pip via `apt` and install it with [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), which is independent of `apt`.

Now both commands work well.